# Finding variance for binomial distribution

Tags: probability

James buys $8$ out of the $20$ tickets in $24$ raffles at his school. Find the expected value and standard deviation for the number fo James' wins.

I correctly calculated $E(X) = 3.6$ by the distribution $X\sim B(192, 1/20)$, so the variance should be $192\times 1/20 \times 19/10$, but this is wrong, thus the sd is wrong. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but this is wrong, thus the sd is wrong. Why?

Your parameters are wrong.

> > James buys 8 out of the 20 tickets in 24 raffles at his school.

In each of the raffles, James has a *success rate* of $8/20$.   Each ticket is equally likely to win, and he buys eight of the twenty.

There are twenty four-raffles; this is the *amount of trials*.   There is only one winning draw in each raffle, no matter how many tickets you buy in it.

The count for successes among $24$ raffles will have a distribution of $\mathcal{Bin}(24, 8/20)$.

Comment: how come my expected value is still correct then?

Comment: The errors cancel, @user71207 .  In the formula $\mathsf E(X)= np$, your $n$ is too high, and your $p$ too low, but by the same factor .  $np= (8n)(p/8)$.  However, that shall not be the case in the formula $\mathsf{Var}(X)=np(1-p)$